# Logback not working with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, logback, c3p0, hibernate-annotations

i'm trying to use logback with hibernate, seems so easy but i can't get it working

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <!-- DB Properties -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- DB Connection -->
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> XXXXXXXXXXXXX</property>
    <property name="connection.username">XXXXXXXXXX</property>
    <property name="connection.password">XXXXXXXXXX</property>


    <!-- c3p0 config  -->

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>     
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>


</session-factory>
```

logback.xml

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>c:/timesheet.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
            %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>c:/timesheet.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
        <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
        <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

</appender>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ALL"/>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

console output

Hibernate: select this_.id_utente as id1_2_3_, this_.valido as valido2_3_, aziendagru2_.id_azienda_gruppo as id1_0_0_, aziendagru2_.logo as logo0_0_, aziendagru2_.nome_azienda as nome3_0_0_, aziendagru2_.sottotitolo_due as sottotit4_0_0_, aziendagru2_.sottotitolo_uno as sottotit5_0_0_, livello3_.id_livello as id1_3_1_, livello3_.descrizione as descrizi2_3_1_, utentianag4_.id_utente_anagrafica as id1_1_2_, utentianag4_.cognome as cognome1_2_, utentianag4_.nome as nome1_2_ from ts_utenti this_ left outer join ts_aziende_gruppo aziendagru2_ on this_.id_azienda_gruppo=aziendagru2_.id_azienda_gruppo left outer join ts_livelli livello3_ on this_.id_livello=livello3_.id_livello left outer join ts_utenti_anagrafica utentianag4_ on this_.id_utente_anagrafica=utentianag4_.id_utente_anagrafica where this_.username=? and this_.password=?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what's your problem exactly?

Comment: i should see like  "2011-04-23_14:34:08.056 [main] DEBUG select this_.id_utente as id1_2_3 ". this output "hibernate: select this...." is the same output that i have if i don't use logback.

Comment: use `DEBUG` instead of `ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

The console output you see there is because you have this in your hibernate config:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

This tells hibernate to log sql prepared statements to the console.

It's hard to tell from your question whether logback logging is working fine otherwise, but if it isn't [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-logging-in-hibernate-logback/) is a pretty good (if a little outdated; just update the version numbers) tutorial on getting it up and running.

**EDIT**

If the above tutorial is not working then it is likely that you are using a version of Hibernate 4.

In later versions of hibernate the logging framework was switched to JBoss logging from slf4j. This means that slf4j is no longer a Hibernate dependency.

You need to add the newest slf4j JAR to the classpath.

Comment: You don't say in your question, but are you using Hibernate 4 perchance?

Comment: i' NOT using hibernate 4..in my project Libraries:

Hibernate : 3.3.0ga -
Hibernate-commons-annotations: 3.3.0ga -
hibernate-core: 3.3.0ga -
hibernate-c3p0: 3.3.0ga -
sl4j - api: 1.7.2

Comment: logback-access 1.0.11 ; logback-classic 1.0.10;logback-core 1.0.10

Comment: any suggest? however i think that the problem is log4j, because i even tryed log4j alone ( not logback) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Now that is odd. Did you add the [log4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) to the classpath aswell when you tried log4j?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log all Hibernate stuff (which are lots of logs, and will be a real performance issue), use `TRACE` log level instead of `ALL`.

Comment: nothing...still got console output for <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>, not with logback..

Comment: You have not assigned any appender to hibernate logger.